# How to get only the date(mm/dd/yyyy) by using the GETDATE()?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Hello everyone I want to pick the current date of the system by using:

Select GETDATE()

It will give you the result

**04/17/2013 06:37:35**

But I just want **04/17/2013**. Because I don't need the time.

Can anyone please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: RTM - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms187928.aspx

Comment: Have you tried this?
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 101) AS [MM/DD/YYYY]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can convert it to a `DATE`

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())
```

Or convert it to a `VARCHAR`

```
SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(10), GETDATE(), 101)
```

The 101 is the format you've requested

Comment: WHy `VARCHAR(15)` and not `CHAR(10)`? The output will only ever be 10 characters exactly, so there's no need to specify more than that, and there's no reason to make it varying length.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it actually what I want.

Comment: @AaronBertrand lazy coding, didn't want to count!  I updated it to CHAR(10).  I used to use VARCHAR without specifying a length until I read your blog about what can go wrong with that

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 101) AS [MM/DD/YYYY]
```

For more types of date please visit [here.](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Something along the lines of:

select convert(varchar(12), GetDate(), 1)

The convert functions third parameter provides a number of different format options for date format.